# Authorize and IsAuthorized with Custom Authentication in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I've been using [Custom Authentication with MVC 3.0 by Brady Gaster](http://www.bradygaster.com/post/custom-authentication-with-mvc-3.0) as my base.

For the most part, I have everything working. But I'm having an issue with post login. Here's the login code that is pertinent to successful login:

```
SessionPersister.Email = model.Email;
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, false); // added after failure, no impact
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl))
  return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

SessionPersister is exactly like Brady's version except I name the property Email instead.

In my custom Controller that my MVC Controllers inherit:

```
var email = SessionPersister.Email;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
{
  var emp = Employee.GetEmployeeByEmail(email);
  if (emp != null)
  {
    filterContext.HttpContext.User = new ManagerUser(Employee.GetEmployeeByEmail(email));
  }
}
base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
```

Anyway, the issue is that I can successfully login, the HttpContext.User is set and IsAuthorized = true. But for whatever reason, when I RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"), it instead switches me back to the login screen. How do I fix this?

Edit: in Startup.Auth.cs:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
  AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
  LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
  Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
  {
    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
      validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
      regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
  }
});
```

Added to web.config as previously it was authentication mode=none (in system.web):

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

And I have a feeling it is related to OnValidateIdentity after looking at that. Going to do some digging.

Comment: Do  you have something like this in your web.config?
 <authentication mode="Forms">

Comment: yep, 
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>

There is also a mention of the redirect within Startup.Auth.cs. In reality, this is a newer MVC release, but everything else about this seems to work from the example, except this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably not the most eloquent, but do have a solution. I created a new AuthorizeAttribute called CustomAuthorizeAttribute and it handles as such:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
  protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
  {
    if (SessionPersister.Email != null)
    {
      return Employee.GetEmployeeByEmail(SessionPersister.Email) != null;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

And instead of decorating the classes with [Authorize], I used [CustomAuthorize]

Note, this system is just a "if you have a login, you're good" type of thing. If there were roles and what not of importance, there'd need to be more to it.